# Validation Check for repeated data in database

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I encountered a problem that whenever the user create a new record, the program must check whether the data were already created a not. My codes currently have some errors that I couldn't find what does the error lies. Can anyone give me some opinion?? Thanks!

Below were to codes to let you guys have more understanding about my problem.

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            //int[] stations = StationNameList();
            //int[] locations = LocationNameList();
            locationstation ls = new locationstation();
            ls.stationID = Convert.ToInt32(cbStation.SelectedValue);
            ls.locationID = Convert.ToInt32(cbLocation.SelectedValue);

            var checkLS = from CLS in Setupctx.locationstations
                          where CLS.stationID == Convert.ToInt32(cbStation.SelectedValue)
                          where CLS.locationID == Convert.ToInt32(cbLocation.SelectedValue)
                          select CLS;
            if (checkLS = checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This Location Station Has Been Created. Please enter a new Location Station.");
            }     
            else
                    {
                        {
                            Setupctx.locationstations.AddObject(ls);
                            Setupctx.SaveChanges();

                            cbStation.SelectedIndex = -1;
                            cbLocation.SelectedIndex = -1;

                            MessageBox.Show("New Location Station Is Created");
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
```

The columns that needs to be compared were saved in an array

```
private int[] LocationNameList()
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            return Setupctx.locationstations.Select(x => x.locationID).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
        }
    }

    private int[] StationNameList()
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            return Setupctx.locationstations.Select(y => y.stationID).OrderBy(y => y).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have already posted the answers that I managed to found out and its working.

Comment: ... its working ... for now .... :)

Answer (score 0):

A crude way would be to create a unique index on those two columns, and attempt save in a try/catch block.

Comment: I have found out a answer and it's working now. I shall post it here.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is working for me as I figured it out myself.

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            locationstation ls = new locationstation();
            int Stations = Convert.ToInt32(cbLocation.SelectedValue);
            int Locations = Convert.ToInt32(cbStation.SelectedValue);
            ls.stationID = Convert.ToInt32(cbStation.SelectedValue);
            ls.locationID = Convert.ToInt32(cbLocation.SelectedValue);

            var AuthCheck = from Ls in Setupctx.locationstations
                            where (Ls.locationID == Stations && Ls.stationID == Locations)
                            select Ls;

            if (AuthCheck.Count() != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This Location Station Has Been Created. Please enter a new Location Station.");
            }     
            else
            {
                Setupctx.locationstations.AddObject(ls);
                Setupctx.SaveChanges();

                cbStation.SelectedIndex = -1;
                cbLocation.SelectedIndex = -1;

                MessageBox.Show("New Location Station Is Created");     
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good job @rookie, but bear in mind that this code will fail in a multi-threaded environment.